# Installing rake

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, rake

we tried to install rake on our pc but there were following errors.. We even tried updating gems but in vain. We need to run some tasks on rake and dont know how to go abt it.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\nemanich\My Documents\gems>gem install rake-compi    0
.7.0.gem
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Error installing rake-compiler-0.7.0.gem:
    rake-compiler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.5


C:\Documents and Settings\nemanich\My Documents\gems>gem install update_rubygems
 .gem
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem update_rubygems.gem locally or in a repository
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy server? If so, set your HTTP_PROXY environment variable appropriately. This is the sort of error you get when the repository can't be contacted. For example:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8888
```

will set it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the command to update RubyGems. Have you tried `gem update --system`?  You might be able to install Rake after that.

Comment: So what does `gem --version` report now?  (I think the newest version is 1.3.7.)